# grid_selectedindexchanged problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, label

//code in aspx file:

```
        <html>
        <body>
        <form>
        <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onselectedindexchanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged" >



        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RollID" HeaderText="RollID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />


        </Columns>            
        </asp:GridView>
        </div><br /> 

        <asp:label ID="Label" runat="server" text=""></asp:label>

        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

//code behind file:

```
        protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            RowIndex = grid.SelectedIndex;
            GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[RowIndex];
            string a = row.Cells[4].Text;
            Label.Text = "You selected " + a + ".";

        }
```

!!! The question is,though iam able to print the data in the grid view form,but when i select a row,i could not print out the message"You selected..etc.." with the use of "Label" server control.

"could any1 plz sort m out dis issue"...

Comment: When/how do you bind your gridview?  You'll also need to be more specific than "doesn't work".  What, specifically, happens when you execute this code?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the SelectedIndexChanged event.  Instead, use the RowCommand event:

```
protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "Select") {
        int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[RowIndex];
        string a = row.Cells[4].Text;
        Label.Text = "You selected " + a + ".";
    }
}
```

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How are you selecting a row?  You may want to set this attribute on the gridview to allow selection to even take place (that the gridview is aware of) by allowing the control to generate a button:

`AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"`

You can see more information about this [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton.aspx)  Of course, this isn't the only way to create a command button, but you'll have to followup if it won't suit your purposes.